# How to split text file into multiple .txt files or data frames based on conditions in R?

Tags: r

I have an XML file in `.txt` format.

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vNBNGasp-aVlRtaVMzcGlPQzQ/view?usp=sharing]

I want to split this file in such a way I get only the text between `<TEXT>` and `</TEXT>` and save it as a different text file or data frame. Can anyone please help me on how I can do this in R?

I have tried using grep function to extract the text, however I am not able to achieve my objective. I am very new to text mining and it would be really great if anyone can help me in this.

```
test_2=grep("[^<TEXT>] [$</TEXT>]",test,ignore.case=T,value=T)
```

Comment: Pictures of data are not reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I did

```
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)
```

Now this is a little tricky because your document (as shown above) doesn't have a root.  If you wrap it in

```
<mydoc>
...
</mydoc>
```

or something like that, you could use this:

```
doc <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("text.xml"))
df <- vector(length=length(doc))
for (i in 1:length(doc))
{ 
    text_node <- doc[[i]]$children$text
    text <- xmlToList(text_node)
    df[i] <- text
}
```

Now suppose you can't add the artificial root I did above.  You can still parse it as HTML, which is more tolerant of invalid documents.  I also use XPath in this example (which you could in the one above too):

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse("text_noroot.xml")
content <- doc$children$html
textnodes <- getNodeSet(content, "//text")
df <- vector(length=length(textnodes))
for (i in 1:length(textnodes))
{ 
    text_node <- textnodes[[i]]$children$text
    text <- xmlToList(text_node)
    df[i] <- text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) with `XML`

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("test.txt")
sapply(xpathApply(doc, "//*/TEXT"), xmlValue)
```

Then you will get a character vector and do what you want.